Terraform Azure Web app deployment not pulling public forked repository code
Scenario
I'm attempting to deploy a sample .NET Hello World Webapp  to Azure, referencing a forked GitHub repository. The deployment process indicates that it is referencing my forked repository, but the GitHub Actions workflow does not trigger, and the web app is not deployed from the forked repo. I've tinkered with various settings with the terraform config, to no avail.
Issue
Despite configuring the repository and providing the GitHub authentication token, the GitHub Actions workflow is not triggered, and the web app is not deployed from the forked repository. I've also tinkered with setting the manual_integration variable of the source control slot to no avail.
Question:
Is there an additional authentication step or configuration that I'm missing between GitHub and the Azure portal to ensure the deployment triggers and pulls the code from my forked repository?
I am being patient post-deployment and waiting 10 minutes for the site to show. And it does work when deployed manually in the Azure portal.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
Terraform config:
webapp.tf
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "srv_plan" {
  name                = "${local.prefix}service-plan"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku_name            = var.webapp_sku
  os_type             = var.webappos
  tags                = local.common_tags
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "dot_net_web_app" {
  name                          = "${local.prefix}dotnet-app"
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id               = azurerm_service_plan.srv_plan.id
  https_only                    = true
  public_network_access_enabled = false
  enabled                       = true
  webdeploy_publish_basic_authentication_enabled = true

  site_config {
    always_on           = true
    minimum_tls_version = var.tls_version
    application_stack {
      current_stack  = var.stack
      dotnet_version = var.stack_version
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_source_control_token" "source_token" {
  type         = "GitHub"
  token        = var.github_auth_token
  token_secret = var.github_auth_token
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app_slot" "slot" {
  name           = "${local.prefix}app-slot"
  app_service_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.dot_net_web_app.id
  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control_slot" "git_source" {
  slot_id                = azurerm_windows_web_app_slot.slot.id
  repo_url               = var.webapp_repo_url
  branch                 = var.webapp_repo_branch
  use_mercurial          = false
  use_manual_integration = false
  depends_on             = [azurerm_source_control_token.source_token]
  github_action_configuration {
    generate_workflow_file = false
  }
}

variables.tf
variable "webapp_sku" {
  type    = string
  default = "P1v2"
}

variable "webappos" {
  type    = string
  default = "Windows"
}

variable "tls_version" {
  type    = string
  default = "1.2"
}

variable "stack" {
  type    = string
  default = "dotnet"
}

variable "stack_version" {
  type    = string
  default = "v7.0"
}

variable "subresource" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["sites"]
}

variable "webapp_repo_url" {
  type    = string
  default = "https://github.com/ZimCanIT/hello-world-webapp"
}

variable "webapp_repo_branch" {
  type    = string
  default = "main"
}

variable "github_auth_token" {
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
  description = "Token for authorization"
}





Additional authentication step or configuration that I'm missing between GitHub and the Azure portal:

This might be an additional authentication step to be done between GitHub and Azure app service deployments. Providing below should not throw any conflicts during GitHub continuous deployments.
You need to provide  ftp_publish_basic_authentication_enabled = true under resource windows_web_app and also make sure that ftps_state setting under site_config{} is set to AllAllowed.
Also check the generated GitHub token has necessary permissions under github scopes for triggering workflows.
Portal view for the above:

Modified terraform code:
variable "webapp_sku" {
  type    = string
  default = "P1v2"
}

variable "webappos" {
  type    = string
  default = "Windows"
}

variable "tls_version" {
  type    = string
  default = "1.2"
}

variable "stack" {
  type    = string
  default = "dotnet"
}

variable "stack_version" {
  type    = string
  default = "v8.0"
}

variable "subresource" {
  type    = list(string)
  default = ["sites"]
}

variable "webapp_repo_branch" {
  type    = string
  default = "main"
}

variable "github_auth_token" {
  type        = string
  sensitive   = true
  default     = "ghp_4SzTSxxxxxxNqt4"
  description = "Token for authorization"
}
variable "ftps" {
type = string
default = "AllAllowed"

provider "azurerm"{
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg"{
  name   = "Jahnavi"
}
resource "azurerm_service_plan" "srv_plan" {
  name                = "myservice-plannew"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  sku_name            = var.webapp_sku
  os_type             = var.webappos
   is_xenon           = true
   reserved            = true
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "dot_net_web_app" {
  name                          = "mydotnet-app"
  location                      = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  service_plan_id               = azurerm_service_plan.srv_plan.id
  https_only                    = true
  public_network_access_enabled = true
  enabled                       = true
  ftp_publish_basic_authentication_enabled = true

  site_config {
    always_on           = true
    minimum_tls_version = var.tls_version
    ftps_state    = var.ftps
    application_stack {
      current_stack  = var.stack
      dotnet_version = var.stack_version
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control" "source_control" {
  app_id                 = azurerm_windows_web_app.dot_net_web_app.id
  repo_url               = "https://github.com/xxx-Madugula/xxx"
  branch                 = "main"
  use_manual_integration = true
}

resource "azurerm_source_control_token" "source_token" {
  type         = "GitHub"
  token        = var.github_auth_token
  token_secret = var.github_auth_token
}

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app_slot" "slot" {
  name           = "myapp-slot"
  app_service_id = azurerm_windows_web_app.dot_net_web_app.id
  site_config {}
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_source_control_slot" "git_source" {
  slot_id                = azurerm_windows_web_app_slot.slot.id
  repo_url               = var.webapp_repo_url
  branch                 = var.webapp_repo_branch
  use_mercurial          = false
  use_manual_integration = false
  depends_on             = [azurerm_source_control_token.source_token]
  github_action_configuration {
    generate_workflow_file = false
  }
}

Output:

Kudu console >> Files:

